# How to use multiple actions with the same name while routing it using Html.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, html-helper, actionresult, html.beginform

My action methods looks like this :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View ();
}

public ActionResult Index (string Name)
{
  return View ();
}
```

First, the 1st actionmethod(Index without parameters)will be called. And after giving the input, the other action method(Index with parameters) will be called from 1st actionmethod(Index without parameters).

Inorder to redirect to second actionmethod (Index with parameeters), am using the following code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SegmentReport", FormMethod.Get)){}
```

in the first action Method

I tried using HTTPGET and HTTPPOST in order to achieve this

But the second action method is not at all called when I click the submit button which is present in the 1st action method

But when I give different action method name and when I use 2 view, I am able to achieve this.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: is two index method httpget?

Comment: No. 1st method is httpget and second method is httpppost

Comment: remove FormMethod.Get from that statement

Comment: I removed fromMethod.Get . It is hitting that action. But I am getting exception

"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key"

Comment: you need to share your view

Answer (score 1):

Decorate the actions with attribute for `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` differentiaiting first of all:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View ();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index (string Name)
{
  return View ();
}
```

and now if you want to call action which is fot Get  use `FormMethod.Get` in `Html.BeginForm` constructor and use `FormMethod.Post` if you want to call action for Post, btw by default it will use FormMethod as Post if you don't specify it in the contructor.